# Substring from range of two characters

Tags: swift, string, format, range, substring

Im trying to convert a time displaying string to a Int.
The syntax looks like this and i want to extract the integers and multiply the first and add the later to get the time in minutes.

```
12h 10m
3h 14m
16h 0m
```

Since the displayed string can be either hhmm, hmm, hhm or hm I cant substring with a fixed offset. 
I'm trying to substring the string by first finding the " " and then the m. 
In other languages this would be easy but for some reson I cant get it to work in swift.

Please help me, you're my only hope.

Comment: Are both hours and minutes always present or could it be "12h"? Can there be more units (e.g. seconds)? Are the units always separated by a space character? – (Do you like regular expressions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your time components (hour and minutes) using components(separated:) and get the first component (hour), multiply it by 60 and add the last component (minutes) to it.

```
extension String {
    var minutes: Int {
        var minutes = 0
        if let hourChars = components(separatedBy: " ").first?.characters.dropLast(),
            let hours = Int(String(hourChars)) {
            minutes += hours * 60
        }
        if let minChars = components(separatedBy: " ").last?.characters.dropLast(),
            let mins = Int(String(minChars)) {
            minutes += mins
        }
        return minutes
    }
}
```

Testing

---

```
let str1 = "12h 10m"
let minutes1 = str1.minutes   // 730

let str2 = "3h 14m"
let minutes2 = str2.minutes   // 194

let str3 = "16h 0m"
let minutes3 = str3.minutes   // 960
```

Answer (score 1):

i think in your case it's better to spilt the string that you have twice

```
let string = "12h 10m 3h 14m 16h 0m"
var array = string.characters.split(separator: "h").map(String.init)

var result: [String] = []
array.forEach {
   result.append(contentsOf: $0.characters.split(separator: "m").map(String.init))
}

// ["12", " 10", " 3", " 14", " 16", " 0"]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to manipulate with date/time strings only I think you should better use a build-in `DateFormatter` for doing it

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH'h' mm'm'"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2h 10m")!

let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: date) 
// returns 2
let minutes = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: date)
// returns 10
```

Answer (score 1):

best solution for your question is

```
func getTime(time:String)->(Int,Int)
{
    let arry = time.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let hours = arry[0]
    let min = arry[1]

    let indexForHour = hours.index(hours.startIndex, offsetBy: (hours.characters.count - 1))
    let indexForMin = min.index(min.startIndex, offsetBy: (min.characters.count - 1))


    let hour = Int(hours.substring(to: indexForHour))
    let minut = Int(min.substring(to: indexForMin))
    return (hour!,minut!)
}

let str1 = "12h 10m"
let str2 = "3h 14m"
let str3 = "16h 0m"
let firstTime:(hour:Int,min:Int) = getTime(time:str1)
print(firstTime)
let secondTime:(hour:Int,min:Int) = getTime(time:str2)
print(secondTime)
let thirdTime:(hour:Int,min:Int) = getTime(time:str3)
print(thirdTime)
```

**OUTPUT**

(hour: 12, min: 10)

(hour: 3, min: 14)

(hour: 16, min: 0)